# ReferenceError for checking late declared variable with let?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was reading about `let` keywords and went through this code block:

`typeof` behaves differently with Temporal Dead Zone (TDZ) variables than it does with undeclared (or declared!) variables. For example:

```
{
    // `a` is not declared
    if (typeof a === "undefined") {
        console.log( "cool" );
    }

    // `b` is declared, but in its TDZ
    if (typeof b === "undefined") {     // ReferenceError!
        // ..
    }

    // ..

    let b;
}
```

So how can one check its `typeof` as it will always give ReferenceError?
Do we need to use `try ... catch` block as an alternative to `typeof`?

```
  {
    try {
      console.log(typeof(b));
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
    let b;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So how can one check its `typeof` as it will always give ReferenceError?

You can't. Accessing variables before they are declared is a programming mistake.

Comment: So theoretically, there no `typeof` for TDZ variables?

Answer (score 0):

Its always best practice to declared the variable where we going to first use it or declared on the top

```
let b;
if (typeof b === "undefined") {     //No  ReferenceError!
    // ..
}
```

So,it is best way remove from TDZ.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> In ECMAScript 2015, let will hoist the variable to the top of the block. ***However, referencing the variable in the block before the variable declaration results in a `ReferenceError`***.The variable is in a "temporal dead zone" from the start of the block until the declaration is processed.

So in your code you are trying to access a var which is not been declared yet.

Comment: This is very unexpected, because normally `typeof` can be used to safely check the existence of a variable. It is even more unexpected if a variable with the same name already exists in an outer scope, because adding a `let` somewhere further down will suddenly make your code above it break, while I would expect it to create that new variable only at the point of `let` and reference the outer variable above that point...!